# Why does this toggleClass not work?

Tags: jquery, css, css-transitions, transition, toggleclass

I have a button:

```
<div id="headBtn">      
</div>
```

I have a class:

```
.slideout {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(265px, 0, 0);
  position:absolute; left:0;
  transition: -webkit-transform .5s ease;
}
```

I have a function:

```
$('#headBtn').on('click',function(){
    var wrap = $('#wrapper');
    wrap.toggleClass('slideout');
});
```

The aim is to have my `#wrapper` element move to the right using `webkit-tansform`, I then want to toggle that css so it snaps back to the left again.

Right now the `#wrapper` element does snap back to the left for a second but it moves to the right again, as if the css is removed but then applied again.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. It does snap back left and stay there: http://jsfiddle.net/8HmEt/ Where is your javascript block-located maybe that is the issue?

Comment: Thanks @Esa I thought I was just going crazy, so my problem is elsewhere. Why would the position of my block matter?

Comment: @UzumakiDev You will need to post more of your code, because with the limited code you gave us, what you described isn't happening.

Comment: If your code is run multiple times, there would be many click-handlers, which could explain the problem.

Comment: Ohhhh, wait, fixed it, no worries, I'm just stupid. I had another function using hammer.js that had `on('tap',function(){
$(this).removeClass('slideout'); });` this was on the wrapper element itself. SOrry for wasting your time. But you did confirm it wasn't the toggle function itself.

Answer (score 1):

It's because when you are removing the class, you are removing the CSS transition defined in it.  If you apply that transition to all elements, it still works when you remove the class:

```
.slideout {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(265px, 0, 0);
  position:absolute; left:0;
}
* {
  transition: -webkit-transform .5s ease;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6Eq4B/

Comment: Hmm he said the problem was that it snaps to the left and then moves to the right again. This doesn't answer that problem. Though I didn't experience that problem myself when I tested the original code.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are saying?